# How can I make a Windows folder "virtual" like you can with directories in Linux using tmpfs?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I want to make certain directories in Windows Vista/7 "virtual" so they are stored completely in memory and emptied when the machine is powered-down.

With Linux, you just need to add a line in your fstab file to mount a particular directory as tmpfs. Is there some equivalent for Windows? I know there are tools like RAMDisk, but they mount a new virtual disk which is not what I want. I want to be able to map a directory like C:\Users\You\Documents\Tmp to be stored in RAM only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the functionality you are looking for is RamDisk. It enables you to create a virtual disk of the memory. There's quite good info on a free ramdisk, that I've used before, [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/27/free-ramdisk-for-windows-vista-xp-2000-and-2003-server/). If you also want to be able to save the data on the virtual drive upon shutdown and restore it on restart, I'd recommend a more sophisticated, though non-free, RamDisk Plus from SuperSpeed (google it) - very useful. I'm not sure it's able to make some specific folders virtual, though.

Comment: As I said, I don't want a separate virtual drive, I want to make folders on my C:\ drive virtual.

Comment: One way would be to combine RamDisk with Windows symbolic link functionality, i.e. linking the directory to the virtual drive, for example using a tool from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx .

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need: junction + some type of RAM disk. Just tried it out and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I have never used it, but I have heard of others using [IMDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk).

There is no built in way to do it, like there is with Linux.  There are also Commercial Alternatives.. [this one](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) gives you a 4GB ramdrive free, to go bigger, you need a license.

Comment: It gives malware error: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/fef2b4f326df35bc08ff3675226a83111c3889f094dfa2cfbe2bfc9c1d4ce66c/detection

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want its contents physically stored in RAM, or are you more going after a folder which gets emptied between boots? Which is the goal and which is the method?

If you're simply looking for a folder which empties between boots, you could always simply write a batch file to do this and stick it in your startup. Such a batch would look something like:

```
DEL /F /S /Q "C:\My Folder\*.*"
```

This would do it on startup obviously, not on shutdown, but I believe there is a "shutdown scripts" property available through the [group policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) editor, but I have never used a shutdown script, so I have no information on how well they work or not.